# Retries with locked SQLite databases in Poco 1.5.x

Tags: c++, sqlite, poco-libraries

From Poco 1.3.4, `Poco::Data::SQLite::SessionImpl` supported the properties `maxRetryAttempts`, `maxRetrySleep`, and `minRetrySleep` which allowed control over automatic retries if the database was locked. These properties have been eliminated in Poco 1.5.0.

What is the proper way to handle locked database retries using Poco 1.5.x?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like porting this change over to 1.5.x was simply forgotten. A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/248) has been created.